# A MeijerG function does not accep arguments wrapped in "*Form" for numeric evaluation

Tags: special-functions, number-representation, python

I get the following Meijer function as a result of a symbolic integration:

```
expr = MeijerG[{{1, 3/2}, {}}, {{1, 1}, {1/2}}, x].
```

I try to calculate numerical values of this function for a series of arguments  x > 0. This turns out to be not possible for 'Form'-ed real arguments.

Entering manually, e.g., `x = 0.000000001` and evaluating `expr` for this argument is successful: `expr = 4.42921*10^-8`. However, the execution of `expr` after converting `x` in any "*Form", e.g., `x = ScientificForm[x]`, is left undone (merely above given rhs- definition of `expr` is mirrored, but no error message is given). I have tried this for other formats like `NumberForm`, `DecimalForm`, `AccountingForm` with the same useless output.

For many application programs this problem may not be relevant, because they pass arguments directly to an evaluator. But many applications written in the python language and using an python-Mathematica-interface like the open source CAS Sage are transforming the argument in the scientific form, if abs(x) < 10^(-5). Thus, such applications cannot compute numerical results for small arguments by using the Mathematica version of the  above mentioned MeijerG-function.

Is it possible by any means to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Only use `Form` for _display_. Don't use them in computation. Don't use `x = ScientificForm[x]`. Just use `x`.

Comment: The behavior you are experiencing isn't peculiar to the `MeijerG` function: it is the normal behavior of any function that tries to perform a numeric computation with an argument wrapped with one of `*Form` display wrappers.

Comment: Use parentheses to exclude the `Form` from the definition, e.g., `(x = 0.000000001) // ScientificForm`

Comment: Many thanks for the advices. They are helpful for me to understand the purpose of Mathematica's Forms more clearly. From your infos  I conclude that the problem  might be  located in the mentioned Python-Mathematica-Interface of the open-source CAS `SageMath`. Apparently the python language converts any number < 1.e-5 into a form that Mathematica interprets as  `ScientificForm` .So, I will pass my questtion to the StackExchange forum of Sage in order to find a solution avoiding this format change.

Comment: As announced, I have put the same question to the stack exchange of the open-source sagemath:(https://ask.sagemath.org/question/48908/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-of-numbers-in-the-mathematica-interface/). The answer acknowledges a bug in the Mathematica-interface of Sagemath. In addition, a workaround is presented. From my point of view the answer can be taken as an answer to my question also in this forum. Since I don't know how to answer here my own question, I give  this info as a comment.